# selecting a variable using input

Tags: list, variables, input

i am new python and need to know how to print one of theis list by typing a or b or c, i tried useing if condtions and it's working but what if i have 100 of theis lists is there a better way thanks.

```
letters = input("Select a letter ")

a = ["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa",]
b = ["bbbb","bbbb","bbbb","bbbb",]
c = ["CCCC","CCCC","CCCC","CCCC",]

if letters == "a":
    print(a)
elif letters == "b":
    print(b)
elif letters == "c":
    print(c)
else:
    print("wrong input")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to call `eval`.

```
print(eval("a"))
print(eval(letters))    # beware
```

However, one must **never** directly evaluate any raw input obtained from a user since they can then enter a command that would make the program do something arbitrary, like bypass restrictions, steal data or wipe your files. User input must always be processed or vetted fully:

```
if letters in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    print(eval(letters))       # safe
else:
    print("wrong input")
```

Another way to do it is to use the built-in function locals(). It returns a dictionary of all variables and values accessible within the local scope.

```
if letters in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    print(locals()[letters])
```